# Parsing very large XML using DOM in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, large-data

I'm doing a science project in my college , and I need to parse an archive of metadata, in this case it's too large.
My code is correct, it works to small archive XML, but my problem is that I need to parse an archive about 264 GB.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without more information.  How much of the 264GB will end up in what you actually parse?  It's possible that you could do it with SAX instead of DOM; but it's hard to tell from what you've told us.

Comment: Sorry, I told just thinking in focus about large archive XML. 
I need to delete some tags of archive metadata. In this tags has too much nodes child. So, I just need get the archive of 264GB, and delete the specific tags to create a new archive without the tags deleted.

Comment: OK, Gabi, that makes sense.  I can think of two obvious ways to do this.  One would be to try and express in XSLT which nodes to keep and which to throw away.  Another would be to write a class that implements `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler` (possibly by extending `org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl`), and keeps track as it reads of whether it should be passing events onwards or swallowing them.  As a starting point though, definitely read up on SAX.

Answer (score 2):

DOM is a poor choice for large datasets, as it must load the document and maintain the structure in memory.  DOM is great choice if you need to process the document multiple times in different ways or perform queries across it, but doesn't handle large files very well

If you only need to do a single pass of the document (and don't need to do forward or reverse searching), then you could use a [SAX Parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

This basically uses the visitor pattern to provide feedback about the parsing process, but only maintains a small amount of information in memory.

If you need to be able to search the document backwards or forwards or process the document multiple times, you could consider splitting the document into different, logical sections and processing the sections separatly, maybe storing the results in some kind of database for later coalation

Comment: Excuse the delay, but thanks to tell me about SAX Parser. I used this in the other occasion.
To solve my problem I used expression regular - Regex ( developed with Java) . It works very well and fast in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem a while ago, and the best solution we could get was to use a no-sql database to store all the elements. We used MongoDB.

I think in your case it could be the best option, since you already have a program that works properly in small XML files. I don't know how you do it, but I assume you allocate some dynamic memory every time you detect a new element. Instead of doing that, put these information in a registry of a MongoDB. Afterwards you'll be able as well to navigate through the entire structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to put the data in an XML database, or you need to use a streaming approach that doesn't hold the whole file in memory. The choice (between the two approaches, and the choice of technology for either approach) depends entirely what you want to do with the information, and you haven't said. For example, if you need to extract a small part of the information, or to extract summary information, then using a streaming XSLT or XQuery processor might do the job.